# Why does the javascript escape function ignore @*/+?

Tags: javascript, escaping

I don't have a use case for this but I was recently asked this very question and [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_escape.asp) helpfully tells you the characters are ignored but not why.

Anyone have any idea why this might be the case?

Thanks,
David

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your source: "The escape() function encodes a string, so it can be read on all computers."
Those characters are standard in the ASCII set, so there's no point in encoding them for this particular purpose.

Comment: This misses the point - the aim is to be able to safely transmit a string inside a *Uri*, which itself uses particular characters for reserved purposes.

Answer (score 7):

The `escape` function is deprecated. Use [`encodeURI`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Functions/encodeURI) and [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Functions/encodeURIComponent) instead.

Comment: The funy thing is that encodeURIComponent that was only implemented by Mozilla in Javascript 1.5 was implemented by IE all the way back to IE 5.5.

Comment: @Gumbo, is there a reference that says `escape` is deprecated? From my test, `escape` and the `encodeURI` and `encodeURIComponent` all do quite different things.

Comment: [Core JavaScript Reference 1.5, Appendix B: Deprecated Features](http://www.webreference.com/javascript/reference/core_ref/deprecat.html)